# paintComponent не рисует, а приложение зависает

Tags: java

Делаю Progressbar и paintComponent должен по чуть-чуть заполнять полосу. Написал следующие методы:

```
GetLastVersionButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
       Preferences user = Preferences.userRoot().node("Node");
       Updater updater = new Updater(user.get("FolderDirectory", null) + File.separator + "client.zip");
       updater.downloadClient();
   }
});
```

Далее получаем файл для скачки:

```
public void downloadClient() {
        try {
            url = new URL(Utils.getClientUrl());
            url.openConnection();
            inputStream = url.openStream();

            Preferences user = Preferences.userRoot().node("Node");
            folder = new File(user.get("FolderDirectory", null));
            if(!folder.exists()) folder.mkdirs();

            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

            urlconnection = new URL(url.toString()).openConnection();
            urlconnection.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
            allB += urlconnection.getContentLength();

            logMsg("Скачивание клиента...");

            while ((b = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
                fileOutputStream.write(buf, 0, b);
                buf = new byte[1024];
                downloadB += b;
                System.out.println(downloadB);
                Main.downloadProgressbar.setValue(downloadB, allB);
            }

            fileOutputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();

        } catch (Exception e){}
    }
```

Специально сделал `System.out.println(downloadB);`, чтоб видеть, что параметры для paintComponent всегда обновляются и таки да, циферки бегут, все как надо.

Если убрать `while` и отправить напрямую `Main.downloadProgressbar.setValue(downloadB, allB);` , то progressbar обновится 1 раз соответственно, с while же просто все падает.

Далее принимаю эти значения, тут также все цифры принимаются и обновляются:

```
public void setValue(int bytesDownload, int bytesTotal) {
        allB = bytesTotal;
        downloadB = bytesDownload;
        repaint();
    }
```

И вот собственно сам paintComponent:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        try {
            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) graphics.create();
            Font font = new Font("Arial",Font.TRUETYPE_FONT ,16);
            String done = "Done!";

            double wProgressBarOnline = 434.0 / allB * downloadB;
            double allMB = new BigDecimal(allB * 0.000001).setScale(2, RoundingMode.UP).doubleValue();
            double downloadMB = new BigDecimal(downloadB * 0.000001).setScale(2, RoundingMode.UP).doubleValue();
            double centerXDone = (441.0 / 2) - g.getFontMetrics(font).stringWidth(done) / 2;
            double centerXProgress = (441.0 / 2) - g.getFontMetrics(font).stringWidth((float)downloadMB + "/" + (float)allMB + " MB") / 2;

            String progress = (float)downloadMB + "/" + (float)allMB + " MB";

            g.setFont(font);
            g.setColor(Color.black);

            progressBarBackground = progressBarOnline = check = ImageIO.read(ADownloadProgressbar.class.getResource("/My/Images/progressbar.png"));

            progressBarBackground = progressBarBackground.getSubimage(41, 29, 441,36);
            progressBarOnline = progressBarOnline.getSubimage(45, 0, (int)wProgressBarOnline + 1, 29);
            check = check.getSubimage(0, 29, 41, 36);

            g.drawImage(progressBarBackground, 0, 0, progressBarBackground.getWidth(), progressBarBackground.getHeight(), null);

            g.drawImage(progressBarOnline, 2, 3, progressBarOnline.getWidth(), progressBarOnline.getHeight(), null);
            g.drawString(progress, (int)centerXProgress, 25);


            g.dispose();
            super.paintComponent(graphics);
        } catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

По итогу такая картина, что при клике по кнопке загрузка файла по факту идет, на компьютер все скачивается, но прогресс бар стоит мертвый + само приложение зависает. Не работают кнопки, окно нельзя передвинуть и т.д., хотя опять же повторюсь, скачивание идет не прерываясь, ошибок при отладки нет никаких.

Буду благодарен если поможете!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что все это вы делаете в одном потоке, и пока у вас весь процесс не закончится, ваша панель не перерисовывается. 
Попробуйте так

```
public void downloadClient() {
        new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    url = new URL(Utils.getClientUrl());
                    url.openConnection();
                    inputStream = url.openStream();

                    Preferences user = Preferences.userRoot().node("Node");
                    folder = new File(user.get("FolderDirectory", null));
                    if (!folder.exists()) folder.mkdirs();

                    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

                    urlconnection = new URL(url.toString()).openConnection();
                    urlconnection.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
                    allB += urlconnection.getContentLength();

                    logMsg("Скачивание клиента...");

                    while ((b = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
                        fileOutputStream.write(buf, 0, b);
                        buf = new byte[1024];
                        downloadB += b;
                        System.out.println(downloadB);

                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Main.downloadProgressbar.setValue(downloadB, allB);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    fileOutputStream.close();
                    inputStream.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Можно подойти по другому и запустить процесс скачивания в [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) - это более правильный вариант.

Comment: Не понимаю, куда ваш пример дописать или как его применять, можно немного детальнее?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, именно строка `Main.downloadProgressbar.setValue(downloadB, allB);` должна вызывать перерисовку. Суть в том чтоб отрисовка и вычисления шли в разных потоках. Я добавил код в ответ.

Comment: Такая же история, снова виснет, не рисует, но скачивает

Comment: В каком именно месте вы вызываете `paintComponent(Graphics graphics)`?

Comment: `Main.downloadProgressbar.setValue(downloadB, allB);` здесь отправляю на `public void setValue(int bytesDownload, int bytesTotal)` и далее уже рисую `repaint();`

Comment: запустите весь метод `downloadClient()` в отдельном потоке... я поправил ответ

Comment: Теперь при нажатии на кнопку вообще ничего не происходит, не качает и не лагает, как не одно так другое :) . Я пытался сделать вообще весь класс через SwingWorker, но что-то тоже не выходит.

`new Thread(new Runnable()` - это подчеркивается и пишет, что новый экземпляр проигнорирован.

Comment: Извините, в конце потока забыл его запустить `}).start();`. Так должно  работать (поправил код).

Comment: Ура, спасибо огромное!