# Не работает repaint в JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Всем привет.
Проблема такова. 
У меня есть объект наследующий JPanel и рисующий картинку. 
Слушатель мыши при нажатии на мышь начинает менять координаты картинки в цикле. 
После каждого шага я вызываю repaint объекта JPanel, но он не срабатывает. В итоге вместо плавного движения картинки я имею мгновенный рывок. Почему метод repaint игнорируется?
Вот пример кода

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main extends JPanel {

    JFrame f;
    Level level;
    Player player;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    private Main(){
        initFrame();
    }

    private void initFrame(){

        f = new JFrame();
        level =new Level();
        player = new Player(level.getLvl());

        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                System.out.println(e.getX());
                System.out.println(e.getY());
                for (int i = 0; i<500; i++){
                    player.coordImgX++;
                    repaint();
                    try {
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(2);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });


        f.add(this);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(1100,600);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g = (Graphics2D)g;
        g.drawImage(level.getImage(),0,0,500,500,null);
        g.drawImage(player.getImage(),
               player.coordImgX,player.coordImgY,90,100,null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможно, оно не успевает перерисовать. За 2 то миллисекунды

Comment: Попробуйте вызвать revalidate() перед вызовом repaint(). Если это не поможет, я бы попробовал вызвать revalidate() и repaint() для фрейма, а не для панели.

Comment: Уже все из этого попробовал

Comment: Почему не успевает? Я меняю координату и потом явно вызываю repaint, но он просто игнорируется?

Comment: На очень похожий вопрос отвечал здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/946389/paintcomponent-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82/946392#946392

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно добавить задержку с помощью `Thread.sleep(int *задержка в миллисекундах*)`. Но вам также нужно перехватывать InterruptedException, которое никогда не случится, если вы не завезёте многопоточность. Поэтому эту инструкцию нужно окружать с помощью блоков `try/catch`.